# Bash find and move files parsed from cvs file data

Tags: bash, csv, find

We have a directory of files which need to be renamed and moved to another directory based on filename information in a cvs file.
The contents of the cvs file are:
A10324687,ahgk1ff0023
A10324698,cru1ff0129

The source folder has the following hierarchy:

```
/Server/Archive/A/AHGK1/AHGK1FF0001_0200/ahgk1ff0023.pdf    
/Server/Archive/B/BFKR3/BFKR3FF0001_0200/bfkr3ff0018.ai  
/Server/Archive/B/BFKR3/BFKR3FF0001_0200/bfkr3ff0018.pdf  
/Server/Archive/B/BFKR3/BFKR3LC0001_0200/bfkr3lc0018.pdf  
/Server/Archive/C/CRU1/CRU1FF0001_0200/cru1ff0129.ai  
/Server/Archive/C/CRU1/CRU1FF0001_0200/cru1ff0129.pdf
```

The results of the script moves and renames

```
ahgk1ff0023.pdf to: /Server/Art/A10324687_ahgk1ff0023.pdf
```

The number of characters in the filename and path vary.
Therefore, I thought it necessary to use a find function with input from the csv file which has the basename minus extensions.
The following script performs well on local files but crawls when run on files
from network shares. Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"DATE: %a %m/%d/%Y  TIME: %r  Auto" >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
date +"DATE: %a %m/%d/%Y  TIME: %r  Auto" >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU_pdf.log
date +"DATE: %a %m/%d/%Y  TIME: %r  Auto" >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/Stamped_PDFs.log
date +"DATE: %a %m/%d/%Y  TIME: %r  Auto" >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/Removed_PDFs.log
#Directory for source files to br moved and renamed
src=/Volumes/Serve/Archive
#Directory in which the files are move to
dest=/Volumes/Serve/Art/
IFS=','
while read new old; do
  ai=$(find $src -name $old.ai)
  pdf=$(find $src -name $old.pdf)
  #Following varible is used to stamp the pdf file with the "New" number from the csv input
  pdfout="$dest$new"_"$(basename $pdf)"
  stamper=/Users/Admin/Desktop/TMP/stamp.pdf
  ait=$(find $src -name $old.ait)
  eps=$(find $src -name $old.eps)
  tiff=$(find $src -name $old.tiff)
  tif=$(find $src -name $old.tif)
  psd=$(find $src -name $old.psd)
  fh8=$(find $src -name $old.fh8)
  fh9=$(find $src -name $old.fh9)
  noExt=$(find $src -name $old)

  #This is where the pdf files get stamped with the "New" number
  echo $new" -> "$old" -> "$pdfout$(basename $pdf) >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU_pdf.log
  gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o $stamper -c "<< /PageSize [792 612]  >> setpagedevice 18 586 moveto /Helvetica-Bold_Italic findfont 14 scalefont setfont ("$new") show"
  pdftk $pdf stamp $stamper output $pdfout verbose | grep .pdf$ >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/Stamped_PDFs.log
  rm -f -v $pdf >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/Removed_PDFs.log

  #The following moves the remaining file types if they exist.
  mv -v $ai $dest${new}'_'${old}.ai >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $ait $dest${new}'_'${old}.ait >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $eps $dest${new}'_'${old}.eps >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $tiff $dest${new}'_'${old}.tiff >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $tif $dest${new}'_'${old}.tif >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $psd $dest${new}'_'${old}.psd >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $fh8 $dest${new}'_'${old}.fh8 >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $fh9 $dest${new}'_'${old}.fh9 >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
  mv -v $noExt $dest${new}'_'${old} >> /Volumes/Serve/Users/Admin/Logs/SKU.log
done < /Users/Admin/Desktop/List.csv
```

Comment: reduce the find to one run with all filenames as targets, i.e. `find $src -name $old.psd -name $old.tif ....` send that into a `| while read filename ; do case ${filename} in *.pdf ) .... ;; *.tif ) ... ;; esac`. If you anticipate having spaces or other non-alphanumerics in your filenames, see about the -print0 option to find and xargs. There are 100s of postings here about that combo. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
dest=/Path/To/File
sed 's|\(.*\),\(.*\)|/\\<\2\\>/s!.*\\(\2.*\\)$!mv -v \&\\t'$dest'/\1_\\1!p|' file.csv |
sed -nf - file_of_files.txt
mv -v /Server/Archive/A/AHGK1/AHGK1FF0001_0200/ahgk1ff0023.pdf  /Path/To/New/File/A10324687_ahgk1ff0023.pdf
mv -v /Server/Archive/C/CRU1/CRU1FF0001_0200/cru1ff0129.ai      /Path/To/New/File/A10324698_cru1ff0129.ai
mv -v /Server/Archive/C/CRU1/CRU1FF0001_0200/cru1ff0129.pdf     /Path/To/New/File/A10324698_cru1ff0129.pdf
```

This takes a `csv` file and generates the commands to move the files in a file of files.

N.B. As @shellter has pointed out you need to refactor your code to gather all your data using as few `find`'s as possible. Once you have a list of files it is far easier to filter the relevant ones out using `sed` or `grep`. You can then use your `csv` file and this list to generate your commands. Good luck!